# How to do this specific row operation in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, summarize

Below is the sample data

```
areatype <- c("01","01","01","01","01","01","01","01","01","01","01","01","21","21","21","21","21","21","21","21","21","21","21","21")
area <- c("000000","000000","000000","000000","000000","000000","000000","000000","000000","000000","000000","000000","016180","016180","016180","016180","016180","016180","016180","016180","016180","016180","016180","016180")
indcode <- c("000000","000000","000000","000000","111","111","111","111","112","112","112","112","000000","000000","000000","000000","111","111","111","111","112","112","112","112")
ownership <- c("00","10","20","30","00","10","20","30","00","10","20","30","00","10","20","30","00","10","20","30","00","10","20","30")
d_202100 <- c(1000,100,500,400,200,20,100,80,300,30,150,120,150,15,75,60,60,8,40,12,66,4,20,42)
d_202200 <- c(1020,102,502,416,206,21,101,84,310,33,153,124,160,16,77,67,64,9,41,14,60,3,21,36)
          
test <- data.frame (areatype,area,indcode,ownership,d_202100, d_202200)
```

the desired result is below. The items in the d_ columns are just to show what is added and what is not. Some context, ownership = 10 is federal government. 910 is the indcode for total federal government. So the desired result is the total employment (the d_ columns are employment) tied to ownership = 10 by unique are (000000 or 016180) in this case.

```
 areatype     area     indcode      ownership      d_202100       d_202200
    01       000000      910           10           20+30           21+33
    01       000000      920           20           100+150         101+153
    01       000000      930           30           80+120          84+124
```

My first attempt at this is below

```
test <- test %>% group_by(area,ownership) %>% summarize(starts_with(d_))
```